# Numerical solution of KdV equation

Tags: differential-equations, mathematical-optimization, approximation

I am dealing with the following Cauchy problem for the KdV equation:

```
w'''[t] + 6 w[t] w'[t] - w'[t] = HeavisideTheta[t]
w[0] = w'[0] = w''[0] = 0
```

My problem is to minimize the distance between `w[t]` and `wG[t]`, where

```
wG[t] = s0 Integrate[G[t1] HeavisideTheta[t - t1],{t, 0, t}]
```

Here `G` is the as the general solution of the following Cauchy problem:

```
G'''[t] + 6 G[t] G'[t] - G'[t] = 0,
G[0] = G'[0] = 0, G''[0] = s.
```

Here `s` is a real number.

Thus, I aim to solve

```
NMinimize[MaxValue[Abs[w[t] - wG[t]]],{s, s0}]
```

with respect to $s$ and $s_0$ when `0 <= t <= 5`.

Note that I do not want to reduce the order of the KdV equation as it is usually done by integrating it with respect to $t$ and neglecting the integration constant.

My attempt. First, I get the numerical solution of the original KdV:

```
theta[t_] := 0.5 (1 + Tanh[100 t])
f[t_] := theta[t]
solw = NDSolve[{w'''[t] + 6 w[t] w'[t] - w'[t] == f[t], w[0] == 0, 
    w'[0] == 0, w''[0] == 0}, w, {t, 0, 20}];
wsol[t_] := Evaluate[w[t] /. solw]
```

Then, I get the numerical solution the equation for the Green's function:

```
solG = ParametricNDSolve[{G'''[t] + 6 G[t] G'[t] - G'[t] == 0, 
    G[0] == 0, G'[0] == 0, G''[0] == s}, G, {t, 0, 20}, {s}, 
   MaxSteps -> Infinity, Method -> {"ParametricCaching" -> None}];
GGreen[t_, s_] := Evaluate[G[s][t] /. solG]
```

And finally, I compute $\tilde{w}$ by Simpsons's rule:

```
En = 50;
T[n_] := t/En n
GsolSimp[t_, s_, s0_] := 
 s0 t/(3 En) (GGreen[T[0], s] f[t - T[0]] + 2 Sum[GGreen[T[2  n], s] f[
        t - T[2  n]],{n, 1, En/2 - 1}] + 4 Sum[GGreen[T[2  n - 1], s] f[
        t - T[2  n - 1]],{n, 1, En/2}] + GGreen[T[En], s] f[t - T[En]])
```

When I run the command

```
NMinimize[{Max[
   Table[Abs[wsol[t] - GsolSimp[t, s, s0]], {t, 0, 5, 0.1}]], 
  0 <= s <= 1, -10 <= s0 <= 10}, {s, s0}, 
 Method -> {"RandomSearch", "SearchPoints" -> 100}]
```

it computes about several hours. The problem get worse if I consider higher order terms like

```
wG[t] = s0 Integrate[G[t1] HeavisideTheta[t - t1],{t, 0, t}] + s1 Integrate[G[t1] t1 HeavisideTheta[t - t1],{t1, 0, t}]
```

I suspect that this is because of `ParametricNDSolve`, since when I use `NDSolve` with fixed values of `s`, `NMinimize` works well.

So, my question is: is there a way of fast minimization of the distance with respect to `s` and `s0` simultaneously?. Thank you very much in advance.

**Some plots**
When I use 2 terms for `wG[t]`, the two solutions are as follows:
[image: <code>wsol[t]</code> and <code>wG[t]</code>]

while 3 terms give the following plot:

[image]

But to get this I need to run the code for over 30 times for different values of `s`.

Answer (score 2):

A more or less clean approach, which relies on interpolating functions, `Interpolation`:

```
Clear[w, G, wG, distance]
w = NDSolveValue[{w'''[t] + 6 w[t] w'[t] - w'[t] == UnitStep[t], w[0] == w'[0] == w''[0] == 0}, w, {t, 0, 5}];
wG = ParametricNDSolveValue[{G'''[t] + 6 G[t] G'[t] - G'[t] == 0, G[0] == G'[0] == 0, G''[0] == s, wg'[t] == s0 G[t], wg[0] == 0}, {wg, G}, {t, 0, 5}, {s, s0}];
distance = Interpolation[Flatten[Table[{s, s0, NMaximize[{Abs[w[t] - wG[s, s0][[1]][t]], 0 <= t <= 5}, t][[1]]}, {s, 0, 3, .5}, {s0, 0, 5, .5}], 1]];
NMinimize[{distance[s, s0], 0 < s < 3, 0 < s0 < 5}, {s, s0}]
(* {0.388008, {s -> 2.14084, s0 -> 0.408041}} *)
```

[image]

It seems you are measuring distances with the $L^\infty$ norm; if you were to content yourself with an $L^1$ or $L^2$ norm, I guess one could speed up the computation a bit. If you want to consider more complex problems, then perhaps it will be necessary to do so, but I don't know whether such norms are acceptable for your problem.

Comment: Thank you for your approach. I will check it now. Is there a way to consider also higher order terms of the form:

`wG[t] = Sum[s[n] Integrate[t1^n g[s][t1]] UnitStep[# - t1],{n, 0, N}]`
for a given `N` and minimize the distance with respect to `s[n]` simultaneously?

Regarding the choice of norm. Actually, any norm can be used as soon as the two solutions get closer at least graphically.

Comment: @AsaturKhurshudyan Yes, it is rather easy: just replace `s0 Integrate[...]` by `s0 Integrate[...] + s1 Integrate[ t1 ...] + ...` with as many terms as you wish. Note that the complexity grows fast with the number of parameters $s_i$, so it will take a lot of time.

Comment: I replaced the constraint `0 < s0 < 1` by `-10 < s0 < 10` (1 term) and it is still running. Maybe I should replace `Integrate[...]` by `NIntegrate[...]` or by Simpson's rule?

Comment: @AsaturKhurshudyan Indeed, it takes more time, but replacing `Integrate` will not probably help (it is a rather fast operation, acting on an interpolating function, and it is essentially equivalent to `NIntegrate`). I'll check if memoization can speed things up a bit, and I'll let you know.

Comment: @AsaturKhurshudyan I cleaned up the code a bit, and made it faster. I will now check whether adding more terms improves the approximation or not.

Comment: Actually, I do not understand why do you use `NMaximize` instead of `Max` or `MaxValue` in the definition of `distance`.

Comment: @AsaturKhurshudyan You have a point, but I was about to leave. I'll check again later on, and if I can simplify the code further, I'll update the post.

Comment: I noticed that `wG` is a highly oscillating function of `s`, probably that's the reason why it coputes so long. I added higher order terms and run your code, it computes already 6 hours.